# Bootstrap fixed navigation jumps when scrolling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've worked with Bootstrap for a while and never come across this problem. I want the navigation to remain fixed at the top of the page, but when I scroll past the carousel it jumps/glitches. I hope you can see it, I'm using Chrome.

When I remove the carousel, it works perfectly, but I can't see any errors. Can anyone spot anything obvious?

My fixed navbar code:

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    ....
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the `navbar` class to your header tag.

Change this:

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

To this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

And add this to your css:

```
.navbar-fixed-top  {
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It still glitches when the navbar moves over the text.

Comment: That looks like a winner!! Thanks for your help, much appreciated!